# Authorizations are not set -- QBXML SDKV12

Tags: qbxml

I have Opened the connection, set the authorizations (Ex: PutIsReadOnly) and the hResult is 0.  Then I did BeginSession and received a ticket and hResult of 0.  But the authorizations don't seem to have taken effect.  To make matters a little stranger, I then query the authorizations (Ex: GetIsReadOnly) and I get an hResult 0x8004040C (BeginSession has not been called or did not succeed).  BUT the next thing the program does is query the customers and it returns records without a problem.

I don't understand how I can get an hResult that says BeginSession did not run or succeed when the program has a ticket and can get customers from QB.

The program is in WinDev and I would be happy to post code if someone thinks that would be helpful.  Every other aspect of the program works fine except for authorizations.  I figured that if I did not have the connection correct to IAuthPreferences2 that I would have gotten an exception or hResult <> 0.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: More than likely, the permissions are too restrictive for some of the data and not others, that is the reason some of it fails and the other works.